# Updating record in a dynamically generated table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build a staff area in an e-commerce website that allows staff to view a table of available products, edit their details and update them with a button click.

Currently I've been having trouble with the actual update function, as my request inputs have been returning null, meaning the query builder fails. I also can't seem to figure out a good way to uniquely identify each input in my table, which is probably what the main problem is.

**EDIT** Problem solved. Form tags had to wrap each row, and thanks to all who gave advice on input arrays. Code shown below:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="jumbotron text-center clearfix">
@foreach($products as $index => $product)
@if ($index == 0)
    <h2>{{$product->category}} Products </h2>
@endif

@endforeach
</div>
<table id="orders" class="table table-striped table-inverse">
<thead>
    <tr id='tableHeader'>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Slug</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Cost (£)</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

        @foreach ($products as $product)

            <tr>
            <form action="{{ url('staff/storeUpdateProduct', [$product->id]) }}" method="POST" class="side-by-side">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <td><input id="{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="id[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->id }}" readonly></td>

                <td><input id="product_name[{{ $product->id}}]" type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->product_name }}"></td>

                <td><input id="slug[{{ $product->id}}]" type="text" class="form-control" name="slug[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->slug }}"></td>

                <td><input id="quantity[{{ $product->id}}]" type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->quantity}}"></td>

                <td><input id="cost[{{ $product->id}}]" type="text" class="form-control" name="cost[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->cost }}"></td>
                <td>


                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" value="Update">

                </td>
                </form> 
            </tr> 
        @endforeach

</tbody>
```

And the new Controller code:

```
 /**
 * Updates product details.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param String $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function storeUpdateProduct(Request $request, $id)
{

    $product = Product::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();

    /*dd([
        $request->product_name[$id],
        $request->slug[$id],
        $request->quantity[$id],
        $request->cost[$id]
        ]);*/

    $product->product_name = $request->product_name[$id];
    $product->slug = $request->slug[$id];
    $product->quantity = $request->quantity[$id];
    $product->cost = $request->cost[$id];

    $product->save();

    return redirect()->route('staff.updateProducts');
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is allowed $request->product_name_.$id, use sprintf('%s_%s', $request->product_name, $id) to concat it.

Comment: Yeah I was pretty sure that wasn't allowed, but it was my last attempt at trying something I hadn't tried yet

Comment: you can assign input name as `array` with `product_id` as `key`

Comment: Like: `name="cost[{{$product->id}}]"`

Comment: Great, I'll try that and see if it helps

Comment: So would I be doing something like $product->product_name = $request->product_name[$id]; in my controller?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<form action="{{ url('staff/storeUpdateProduct', [$product->id]) }}" method="POST" class="side-by-side">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" value="Update">
</form>
```

Only `submit` button is inside the `form` tag. You have to put all the `input` as well as `submit` button inside the form like:

```
<form action="{{ url('staff/storeUpdateProduct', [$product->id]) }}" method="POST" class="side-by-side">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

@foreach ($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td><input id="{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="{{ $product->id}}" value="{{ $product->id }}" readonly></td>

    <td><input id="product_name_{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name_{{ $product->id}}" value="{{ $product->product_name }}"></td>

    <td><input id="slug_{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="slug_{{ $product->id}}" value="{{ $product->slug }}"></td>

    <td><input id="quantity_{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity_{{ $product->id}}" value="{{ $product->quantity}}"></td>

    <td><input id="cost_{{ $product->id }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="cost_{{ $product->id }}" value="{{ $product->cost }}"></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" value="Update">
    </td>
</tr> 
@endforeach
</form>
```

then you will get the value using `Request` or `Input::get()`

Comment: Is there a way to effectively get the inputs tied to a particular product? I'm aware that $request->product_name_.$id isn't gonna work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)

        <tr>
            <td><input id="{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="{{ $product->id}}" value="{{ $product->id }}" readonly></td>

            <td><input id="product_name_{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->product_name }}"></td>

            <td><input id="slug_{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="slug[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->slug }}"></td>

            <td><input id="quantity_{{ $product->id}}" type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[{{ $product->id}}]" value="{{ $product->quantity}}"></td>

            <td><input id="cost_{{ $product->id }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="cost[{{ $product->id }}]" value="{{ $product->cost }}"></td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ url('staff/storeUpdateProduct', [$product->id]) }}" method="POST" class="side-by-side">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" value="Update">
                </form> 
            </td>
        </tr> 
    @endforeach
```